# Why does Android click area have a wider radius than touchstart? How can I make it consistent?

Tags: javascript, android, click, touchstart

I have a simple rectangular anchor tag. I used jQuery to respond to `click` and `touchstart` events with the following:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#button").on("click touchstart", function(e) {
          $("#log").append(e.type + "<br/>");
      });
  });
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <a id="button" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
<div id="log">Log:<br></div>
```

The CSS is simple:

```
  #wrapper {
      padding:50px;
  }
  #button {
      display:block;
      width:200px;
      height:40px;
      text-decoration:none;
      color:#333;
      background-color:#efefef;
      border:0px;
      padding:0px;
      margin:0px;
  }
```

[I built this as a demo to show the problem I'm talking about.](http://bit.ly/1FcXnvW)

When you tap the edge of the rectangular anchor, only the `click` event is fired. When you tap the center of the area, both `click` and `touchstart` are fired.

Why is it that only `click` seems to be triggered with the fat-finger detection? Is there a way to make the `touchstart` event also work with fat fingers?

---

#### Animation of problem

Only click is fired on edge tap

[image: touch firing click only]

Expected behavior, both events

[image: touch firing both events]

Comment: hey trevor, do you have the example you posted on http://www.trevorsimonton.com/androidissue/index.html - it looks like it's down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problem

The `click` event on touch devices is meant to **emulate** a *click* based on *tapping*. There was a big problem here, because touch interfaces are significantly different from desktop interfaces. The biggest difference? Mouse clicks are a lot more precise than finger touches. To ensure that desktop sites and applications would at least be somewhat useful the behaviour you're observing was designed. That way a user on a mobile phone would still be capable of clicking a small link, even though his fingers are actually too imprecise to accurately click the link.

## The solution

You aren't going to like this, but the solution is simply not to use `click` events on touchscreen devices. This is typically not done because the `click` event is actually triggered around 300ms after the `touchEnd` event and thus feels laggy either way (the delay is there to wait for a double tap) and now you have another reason to not use it.

## The hard part

Devices that have both a touchscreen *and* a mouse. Your choice whether you want to bother with those. Personally I tend to just go with them emulating clicks and living with the extra lag whilst using `touch` events on mobile devices, but if you take the time you can create far more carefully crafted solutions probably.

Comment: I'm trying to get a desktop site to be touch friendly as a temporary fix. The client doesn't want to do a fully responsive site or a mobile site yet, they just want the desktop site to work with hover/touch events. iOS has a way of treating the first tap as hover, which expands the old dropdown nav. I'm trying to recreate this on Android. I mostly have it working, but this touch radius problem causes it to act inconsistently if you just miss the navigation element. I unfortunately need to rely on `click` here. Since this is a temporary fix, I'll probably have to say "no solution"

Comment: @tmsimont As a *temporary* solution you can just set a variable based on useragent (checking for touch support is pretty hard) and use it to either bind the touch event *or* the click event.

Comment: true.. I was hoping to support devices like my ASUS tablet where i might sometimes be using the mouse and other times be using the touch screen, too. That's why I've been avoiding that. I was hoping somebody might come in with some magic javascript that either narrows the wide radius of the touch trigger or expands the radius of touchstart...

Comment: @tmsimont Well, the thing to realize is that if you cancel the touch event the click event isn't triggered, so that's how you build proper support. But getting that /right/ is harder than it sounds (part of the reason of which is that surface windows tablets and asus android tablets both work in different ways).

Comment: yep. I ran into some huge headaches trying to support both, but I did get it working on windows touch+mouse, android and iOS.. this wide touch range is my only remaining headache. for now i had to tell the client there's no way around it unless we rebuild with the method you're describing. i suppose that's just the way it is!